# Android support multiple screen

Tags: android

I decompilated some android project, I want to get the resolution to
support multiple screen size. I fonund in drawable folders, the add -v4 suffix such as drawable-hdpi-v4,drawable-hdpi-v4,what it mean? What problems can it resolve? 
Then I was confused about screen support, if the same screen density
but diffrent screen size,how can i support? i have two android
devices,a resolution 480*845 and another 1024*600,but the screen
density all 240, the too more space left in big one? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: What does *decompilated* mean?

Answer (score 0):

Android Developer Guide has a detailed explanation for your question: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

-v4 means Platform Version (API level).

This is because an activity/resource may have different looks on different platforms, especially the notification areas on Android 2.x and 4.x

Comment: I know -v4 means version,i want to know it means the min version the project support?

Answer (score 0):

The -hdpi, -v4 etc are qualifiers that allow you to control how the system select layout/drawable etc. based on the characteristics of the current device screen. In you case the new "size qualifiers" may help you out. See the official guide [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more details (especially the "configuration qualifiers" part and the "size qualifiers" part).